# Calling c++ generic method from C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I created a C++ 64-bit library as follows

```
// UnManagedCLI.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace UnManagedCLI {

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memset", CallingConvention = CallingConvention::Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    extern IntPtr MemSet(IntPtr dest, int c, int count);

    //[System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute]
    public ref class Unmanaged sealed
    {
    public:
        static void Free(void* unmanagedPointer)
        {
            Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(unmanagedPointer));
        }

        generic <typename T> where T : value class
            static IntPtr New(int elementCount)
        {
            return Marshal::AllocHGlobal(sizeof(T) * elementCount);
        }

         generic <typename T> where T : value class
            static IntPtr NewAndInit(int elementCount)
        {
            int sizeInBytes = sizeof(T) * elementCount;
            IntPtr newArrayPtr = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(sizeInBytes);
            MemSet(newArrayPtr, 0 , sizeInBytes);
            return newArrayPtr;
        }

        generic <typename T> where T : value class
            static void* Resize(void* oldPointer, int newElementCount)
        {
            return Marshal::ReAllocHGlobal(IntPtr(oldPointer), 
                IntPtr((int) sizeof(T) * newElementCount)).ToPointer();
        }
    };
}
```

From C# I include it as a reference, check unsafe code in the build, and then in main do this:

```
using UnManagedCLI;

unsafe class TestWriter
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Unmanaged un;

        //I can't access any of the C++ methods in here?
    }
}
```

when I say `un.` I don't see any of the methods in the C++/CLI library? It builds and runs fine, but I cannot access the C++ at all.

Comment: Why do you call `memset` through P/Invoke? You can `#include <memory.h>` and call it directly.

Comment: Tip: Code completion is great but the compiler rules. In either case, type the code you want. If Intellisense gives you an message that you can use, fine. Otherwise, see what the compiler says. You could have gotten a message like "Member 'Class.method()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the methods of your C+++/CLI class (Unmanaged) are static. Try using the Unmanaged.Method syntax in C# (you don't have to create an object).